# 繰り返し予定の終了日を取得したい

Tags: google-calendar-api

登録されている繰り返しイベントのうち、終了日が設定されていないイベントをリスト化し、
そのイベント作成者にslackで警告DMを送るという実装をしたいです。

リファレンスやネット記事を何度も探しましたが、
終了日を設定するメソッドはあるものの、取得するメソッドは存在せず
取得する方法も見つけ出すことができませんでした。

ということは、現時点で終了日を直接的に取得する方法は無いんじゃないかと諦めてましたが
もし、取得方法をご存知の方いればぜひご教示いただきたいです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

[Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) で以下のパラメータが関連しそうです。

> #### Events: list
>
> 指定されたカレンダーの予定を表示します。
>
> | パラメータ名 | 値 | 説明 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | singleEvents | boolean | 定期的な予定をインスタンスに展開し、1 回限りの予定と定期的な予定のみを返すか、定期的な予定自体は返さないか。（省略可）デフォルトは False です。 |

参考:
[Fetch Recurring events with google calendar api v3 in php - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16066452/2322778)